# How do I make this checkbox styling work in Edge?

Tags: css, checkbox, microsoft-edge, webkit-appearance

I'm styling my checkboxes to look like toggle switches which works beautifully in Chrome, UC Browser, Safari for Windows and is a bit choppy in Firefox but acceptable.  Unfortunately in Edge it doesn't work at all.

I've looked through the CSS properties I'm using and it appears as though all are supported by Edge so I don't understand what I'm missing.

```css
.toggle{
      width:34px;
      height:16px;
      border-radius:40px;
      position:relative;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin:2px 0 0 0px;
      box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c6c6c6,#e3e3e3);
      cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;pointer:hand;
      outline: 0;
    }
    .toggle:checked{
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#77178F,#AD73BB);
      box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .toggle:before {
      content:'';
      letter-spacing:1px;
      color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
      font-size:10px;
      font-weight:100;
      text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
      width:7px;
      height:7px;
      padding:2px;
      top:2px;
      left:2px;
      position:absolute;
      border-radius:40px;
      background: linear-gradient(#ebebeb,#f1f1f1);
      box-shadow: -2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
            -1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
            inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
      transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    .toggle:checked:before {
      left:20px;
      background:#f1f1f1;
    }
    .toggle:checked:after {
      background: linear-gradient(#d8eec4,#5fa718);
      box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px #417f0b,
            inset 1px 1px 2px #5b9f1a;
    }
```

```html
<input type=checkbox class=toggle>
```

It looks to me like `-webkit-appearance:none` is not doing what it's supposed to (hide the original checkbox) but that also is supposedly supported.

If anybody has any experience with this issue and can give me some insight it would be much appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, Edge will be updated to use the chromium engine in a future release which will make this problem go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to hide a checkbox, wrap it with another element (e.g. label) and add a sibling to the checkbox. You can find an example of checkbox-switch here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp.

---

Or you can adjust code below:

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox] { 
  opacity: 0; /* or use display: none; to hide default checkbox */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.toggle .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#ebebeb, #f1f1f1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.toggle .slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .slider {
  background: linear-gradient(#77178F,#AD73BB);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.toggle .slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.toggle .slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I was really hoping to not have to add new elements for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @Vincent, I've found similar topic here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11947102/. Microsoft Edge Team's member said, that input elements should not support before and after pseudo elements.

Comment: Great find Irina!  That explains why I'm hitting this issue.  Unfortunate that MS has decided to buck the trend.  Edge has been shaping up to be quite a good browser but I hope they don't start going down the IE road again (doing things differently than everyone else) cause we all know how that turned out.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a label to meet your requirements as a workaround. In this way you could connect a label with a checkbox and apply the styles to the label instead of the checkbox itself.

Here is my testing code.

CSS.

```
    .toggle {
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;           
    }
        .toggle + label {
            width: 34px;
            height: 16px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            position: relative;
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            background: linear-gradient(#c6c6c6,#e3e3e3);
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: 0;
            display: inline-block;               
        }

            .toggle + label:before {
                content: '';
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
                font-size: 10px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
                width: 7px;
                height: 7px;
                padding: 2px;
                top: 2px;
                left: 2px;
                position: absolute;
                border-radius: 40px;
                background: linear-gradient(#ebebeb,#f1f1f1);
                box-shadow: -2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
                transition: all 0.4s;
            }

        .toggle:checked + label {
            background: linear-gradient(#77178F,#AD73BB);
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }
    .toggle:checked + label:before {
        left: 20px;
        background: #f1f1f1;
    }
    .toggle:checked + label:after {
        background: linear-gradient(#d8eec4,#5fa718);
        box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px #417f0b, inset 1px 1px 2px #5b9f1a;
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="mycheckbox">
<label for="mycheckbox" />
```

[image: running result]

Answer (score 0):

Adding another flexible variation of the selected answer to the mix: https://codepen.io/hawatt/pen/MWKyJJZ

HAML

```
.toggle-switch
  %input{type: 'checkbox',  id: 'away-from-desk' }
  %span.toggle-handle
  %label{'for' => 'away-from-desk'} Away from desk
```

SCSS

```
$toggle-width: 2.8rem;
$toggle-height: 1.5rem;
$toggle-handle-diameter: calc(#{$toggle-height} * 0.8);

.toggle-switch {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: $toggle-width;
    height: $toggle-height;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: $toggle-height;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    z-index: 0;
    text-indent: -5000px;
  }
  .toggle-handle {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: $toggle-handle-diameter;
    height: $toggle-handle-diameter;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 0.35rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
  }
  input:checked,
  input.enabled {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    & + .toggle-handle {
      left: calc(#{$toggle-width} - #{$toggle-handle-diameter} - 0.25rem);
    }
  }
  label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude, that's some very bizarre "HTML" you have there.  Never seen that before.

Comment: @Vincent :D Sorry that's HAML, an indentation based, pre-processed, short-hand version of HTML